How to ignore services and messages with protoc in openapiv3 generation
I am trying to ignore service services from being generated in my proto to openapiv3 generation using protoc.  With swagger and v2 generation, I was able to accomplish this with:
service WordValidator {
  option (google.api.api_visibility).restriction = "INTERNAL"; // doesn't generate the service in v2
  
  rpc Validate(ValidateRequest)
      returns (ValidateResponse) {
    option (google.api.method_visibility).restriction = "INTERNAL";  // does not generate openapi spec for this method in v2
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/validate/{word}"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}

It seems that google.api.api_visibility is not used by v3 in protoc-gen-openapi from gnostic but it was used by protoc-gen-openapiv2 from grpc gateway
The command is along the lines of:
protoc --openapi_out=../go/webserver/openapi {proto_files}
How do you ignore services and message in openapiv3 generation with protoc?

When you reference protoc-gen-openapiv2 do you mean this plugin from the grpc-gateway repo? When you reference protoc-gen-openapi do you mean the gnostic repo plugin?

For Gnostic, you should annotate the methods that you want exposed (google.api.http)  (and not annotate those you don't).

Yes, those are the ones I'm referring to (I've updated the post).  I'm not sure I am following, I see no annotations for visibility / generation.
I want the google.api.http annotation on every endpoint.  some of these endpoints we don't expose externally, so I don't want them as part of the openapi spec.  In protoc-gen-openapiv2 you can do this with the google.api.method_visibility but  it doesn't seem to affect the generation with gnostic.  I'm not sure if post processing is the way to accomplish this

I see. You said you were "trying to ignore services" and I was proposing that you not annotate methods (because you can't do this with services) by not including an option (google.api.http). I now understand that the grpc-gateway protoc-gen-openapiv2 plugin respected google.api.{foo}_visibility rules but there appears to be no mention of this in Gnostic's protoc-gen-openapi plugin which explains these rules being ignored.
